# Deleted a separate /home directory resulting various error

Tags: partition, kali-linux, windows, home, gparted

I have installed Kali Linux with the separate /home directory option.
Problem is /home directory have larger space, and shortly after I wanted to merge it to my main kali partition.

So since I can't merge it with Gparted inside the working OS, I deleted my /home partition by using Windows Disk Management, thinking that I would be able to merge it after..

How unfortunate I am because now I can't login to Kali and even to my Windows. I can boot to windows until login screen, but after I entered my password it's a black screen.

My question are:
- What is inside that /home directory so it can make me unable to login? Because before I deleted it, I've checked inside and it's empty..

- Why does deleting the partition that belong to other OS can cause my Windows experience a black screen error after login?
- How can I login to my kali again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try to learn GNU/Linux before messing with a specialized tool like Kali?

Comment: I don't think that your problem is kali related. However think again, about whether kali is a good choice for a main OS. Most/all of the tools are available in other Gnu/Linux distros. But kali is hard to use. However kali has benefits for live booting. (unless you have a good reason to use this distro, then choose another).

Comment: @mattdm this isn't a duplicate of that question. but I do agree that OP should probably read it.

Comment: https://kali.training/downloads/Kali-Linux-Revealed-1st-edition.pdf

Comment: Using kali is the only thing that keeps me interested in learning linux, so I'll deal with the problems, but thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3):

[Rescatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) is a free bootable live CD/USB that can repair GRUB and the Windows bootloader. Rescatux has a graphical interface with a menu of operating system rescue tasks. If your hard disk has the MBR partitioning format, you can select the *Restore Windows MBR (BETA)* option to repair the Windows bootloader. If your computer has UEFI firmware, you can select among the UEFI boot options.

**Boot options:**

- (>=0.41 beta 1) Update UEFI order
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Create a new UEFI Boot entry
- (>=0.41 beta 1) UEFI Partition Status
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Fake Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Hide Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Check UEFI Boot

**GRUB options:**

- (>=0.40 beta 11) Easy GNU/Linux Boot Fix
- Restore GRUB and GRUB2
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Update any GRUB2 menu
- Update Debian/Ubuntu GRUB menus

**Windows options:**

- Restore Windows MBR (BETA)
- Clear Windows passwords
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Promote a Windows user to Administrator role
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Unlock Windows user

**Password options:**

- Change GNU/Linux Password
- Regenerate sudoers file
- Clear Windows passwords

[image]
<sup>**Rescapp is a nice wizard that will guide you through your rescue tasks.**</sup>

#### How to make a Rescatux live USB from Ubuntu

1. Install GParted partition editor with `sudo apt install gparted`.
2. Insert a USB flash drive and check if the boot flag has been enabled on the flash drive using the GParted application. Unmount the USB flash drive. Open GParted and select the USB flash drive from the menu list of drives. From the GParted menu select: *Partition* -> *Manage Flags* -> check *boot*.
3. It is **very important** to verify that the device that you are installing the Rescatux live USB to is indeed your flash drive, so that you don't overwrite any of your system or personal files which may make your operating system unbootable. In Ubuntu you can find the device name of the flash drive using the *Disks* application.
4. Unmount the USB partition device. Let's say the USB partition device is `/dev/sdc1`

   ```
    sudo umount /dev/sdc1 # replace sdc1 with the partition name of your USB drive
   ```
5. Change directories using `cd` to the path of the directory where the Rescatux iso file that you downloaded is located.
6. Write the Rescatux iso file to the USB flash drive. In the following command replace `rescatux_0.xxxx.iso` with the name of the Rescatux iso file you downloaded.

   ```
    sudo dd if=rescatux_0.xxxx.iso of=/dev/sdc 
    sudo sync
   ```

Comment: If you can get a Windows login screen with a password prompt, restoring UEFI or MBR boot is very unlikely to help resolve the subsequent problem.